# Simple rectangle pattern with graphics in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, java-2d

So basically when I try to increase the number of the variable which increases the number of rectangles, it starts to overlap. At the moment when i increase the variable to 2, the first column duplicates on top of the second and the second columns duplicates to the third spot where the first column duplicate should be. I'm sure it has an easy fix. I have a feeling that i need to add something to the coordinates but i'm not sure what exactly. Heres the code

```
public class Pattern extends JComponent implements ActionListener{

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4)); 
int width = 100;
int height = 100;
int number = 1;
JTextField tf = new JTextField(String.valueOf(width));
JTextField kl = new JTextField(String.valueOf(height));
JColorChooser color = new JColorChooser();
JCheckBox selection = new JCheckBox();
JTextField howMany =new JTextField(String.valueOf(number));

public Pattern(){

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    paneel.add(new Label("Width:"));
    paneel.add(tf);
    paneel.add(new Label("Height:"));
    paneel.add(kl);
    paneel.add(new Label("Filled in:"));
    paneel.add(selection);
    paneel.add(new Label("Number:"));
    paneel.add(howMany);

    tf.addActionListener(this);
    kl.addActionListener(this);
    selection.addActionListener(this);
    howMany.addActionListener(this);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(color, BorderLayout.EAST);
    color.setPreviewPanel(new JPanel());

}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(color.getColor());
    for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
        if(selection.isSelected()){

            g.fillRect((width)*i, 10, width, height);
            g.drawRect((width)*i, 110, width, height);
            g.drawRect((width)*i+width, 10, width, height);
            g.fillRect((width)*i+width, 110, width, height);
        } else {
            g.drawRect((width)*i, 10, width, height);
            g.fillRect((width)*i, 110, width, height);
            g.fillRect((width)*i+width, 10, width, height);
            g.drawRect((width)*i+width, 110, width, height);
        }
    }




}

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Window");
    window.setSize(1000, 1000);
    window.getContentPane().add(new Pattern());
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(tf.getText());
    System.out.println(kl.getText());
    width = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
    height = Integer.parseInt(kl.getText());
    number =Integer.parseInt(howMany.getText());

    repaint();
}


}
```

Comment: Edited your tags. This is not a design patterns question. Please read the tag wiki (tag info) before using a tag.

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove it

Comment: 1) Don't mix Swing with AWT components.  Those `Label` components should be `JLabel` components. 2) `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(color.getColor());` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(color.getColor());`

Comment: Who are you thanking?  Tip: Add @ChetanKinger (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify the person of a new comment.  BTW - if you're thanking me, note that if I intended that as an answer, I'd have posted an **answer.**  Comments are for ..everything else.  And while I'm here:  If you've changed the `Label` to `JLabel` [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30013687/edit) to show that, but better still post code in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: What is `paneel`? It is not defined. Is it `panel`?

Comment: I'm also confused about extending `JComponent`, are you sure that's the best direct superclass?

Comment: What *exactly* is `number` controlling? At `1` it draws 2x2 squares. What should it draw at `2`? 3x3 squares?